# MySQL summary function on N-th row

Tags: mysql

I try to create a function, that returns the summary on the n-th row, where n defined by the order a query result.
This is what I have:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `fn_inventory_stock_on_note`( fIngredient int, fInventory int, fNote int ) RETURNS float
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE tStock float;  
    DECLARE tNoteRow int;
    DECLARE tDummy int;

    DECLARE rStock float;  
    DECLARE rRow int;

    SET tNoteRow = 0;
    SET @rRow := 0;

    SELECT @rRow := @rRow + 1, b.ID
        INTO tNoteRow, tDummy
    FROM fn_inventory_book b
        LEFT JOIN fn_inventory_book_in bi ON b.id = bi.bookid
        LEFT JOIN fn_inventory_book_out bo ON b.id = bo.bookid
            LEFT JOIN fn_dict_transactions t ON b.transactionid = t.id
    WHERE b.inventoryid = fInventory
        AND ( bi.ingredientid = fIngredient OR bo.ingredientid = fIngredient )
    HAVING b.ID = fNote
    ORDER BY b.date ASC, t.direction ASC;

    SET @rRow := 0;
    SET @rStock := 0;

    SELECT rStock INTO tStock
    FROM ( SELECT @rRow := @rRow + 1 as rRow, @rStock := @rStock + ifnull( if( bi.id is not null, bi.quantity, bo.quantity ), 0 ) * t.direction as rStock
            FROM fn_inventory_book b
                LEFT JOIN fn_inventory_book_in bi ON b.id = bi.bookid
                LEFT JOIN fn_inventory_book_out bo ON b.id = bo.bookid
                    LEFT JOIN fn_dict_transactions t ON b.transactionid = t.id
            WHERE b.inventoryid = fInventory
                AND ( bi.ingredientid = fIngredient OR bo.ingredientid = fIngredient )
            ORDER BY b.date ASC, t.direction ASC ) as q
    WHERE rRow = tNoteRow;

    RETURN tStock;

END
```

Where `fIngredient` and `fInventory` is an id for the query's filter, and `fNote` is a PK from the `fn_inventory_book` table.
The first select gets the required row's number in the order, which works fine.
My problem is in the second query, which in the subquery creates a table with the same filter and order like the first select, with the same row numbers, and the cumulative quantity of each row. And in the main query I filter that with the row number I got in the first select.

At least this is what should happen. But instead of that, when I run the function like:
`select fn_inventory_stock_on_note( 1545, 18, 124167 ) as stock from dual;`
It returns `NULL`, but if I run the second query separately with the same params, I get an amount back.

But not the right number because if I only run the second query's subquery, the row numbers aren't in order (1,2,3,6,7,4,5,8,9,10 instead of 1,2,3,..,10).

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.
Feel free to ask if my description isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution for my problem, but if anyone has a better one, please share it, because I don't think mine is the right one, although it does the job.

```
DROP function IF EXISTS `fn_inventory_stock_on_note`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `fn_inventory_stock_on_note`( fIngredient int, fInventory int, fNote int, fItem int ) RETURNS float
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE tStock float;  
    DECLARE tNoteRow int;

    DECLARE rStock float;  
    DECLARE rRow int;

    SET @rRow := 0;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS stock_temp;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE stock_temp ( num int, BookID int, ItemID int, qty float );
    INSERT INTO stock_temp ( SELECT @rRow := @rRow + 1 as num, q.*
                                FROM ( SELECT b.id as BookID, if( bi.id is not null, bi.id, bo.id ) as ItemID, 
                                            ifnull( if( bi.id is not null, bi.quantity, bo.quantity ), 0 ) * t.direction as qty
                                        FROM fn_inventory_book b
                                            LEFT JOIN fn_inventory_book_in bi ON b.id = bi.bookid
                                            LEFT JOIN fn_inventory_book_out bo ON b.id = bo.bookid
                                                LEFT JOIN fn_dict_transactions t ON b.transactionid = t.id
                                        WHERE b.inventoryid = fInventory
                                            AND ( bi.ingredientid = fIngredient OR bo.ingredientid = fIngredient )
                                        ORDER BY b.date ASC, t.direction ASC ) as q );


    SELECT num INTO tNoteRow
    FROM stock_temp st
    WHERE st.BookID = fNote
        AND st.ItemID = fItem;


    SELECT sum( st.qty ) INTO tStock
    FROM stock_temp st
    WHERE st.num <= tNoteRow;

    RETURN tStock;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```